# Sharepoint visual web part issue with session set own object

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

In sharepoint visual web part when i work with

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)

{
     string name =  "Rai";
     HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"] = name;
}

protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)

    {

          if(HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"] != null)
          {
             var name = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"];
             // todo something else
          }

    }
```

It work for me, but if i replace string by Person object when i click ImageButton1_Click --> ImageButton2_Click i always get null

```
    public class People
    {    
        public string FirstName { get; set; }        
        public string LastName { get; set; }  
    }

protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)     
{     
      People p = new People();         
      p.FirstName = "Rai";         
      p.LastName = "Tan";         
      HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("PeopleInfo", p);     
}

protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)   
{                
       if(HttpContext.Current.Session["PeopleInfo"] != null) // **always null :(**   
       {
          var name = (People)HttpContext.Current.Session["PeopleInfo"]; // awlays null
          // todo something else
       }           
}
```

Is this impossible, or is there another way of accomplishing this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The People class must be marked as serializable if the session state mode is either StateServer or SQLServer.  I believe if the mode is InProc then the class does not have to be marked as serializable, but I'm not totally 100% sure about that.  You may look up the details about serialization here [Basic Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and here [Session-State Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

```
    [Serializable]
    public class People
    {    
        public string FirstName { get; set; }        
        public string LastName { get; set; }  
    }
```

Alternatives:

1. Store the People properties as a delimited string ex) MyFirstName;MyLastName; or JSON string ex) {"Person":{"FirstName":MyFirstName, "LastName":MyLastName}}
2. Store the People data into a database on Button1 click and retrieve the data on Button2 click
3. Store the People data in static variables.
4. Since you are using SharePoint, you could store the people data in a list

There are many alternatives with benefits and disadvantages.  It all depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  If you provide some more detail about your problem, I can give you my best recommendation.

Comment: Dennis Flagg, you are right the People class must be marked as serializable -- im in SQLServer mode ...
Thanks you :)